# How to remove empty spaces between scraped data in csv?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

This is my link extractor. It crawls through links and saves it in a csv file but there is spaces between values that is if a value is saved at row 1, then it saves at row 3 the row 2 is blank. I could remove it from excel itself but excel hangs when there is large amount of data. It is creating me problem when i am trying to load links to **scrape** data from it. How do i save data in such a way that there is no blank spaces? Thanks.

```
import scrapy


class DummySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dummyspider'
    allowed_domains = ['alibaba.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.alibaba.com/countrysearch/CN/China/products/A.html'
                ]

    def parse(self, response):
        link = response.xpath('//*[@class="column one3"]/a/@href').extract()

        for item in zip(link):
            scraped_info = {
                'link':item[0],

            }
            yield scraped_info
```

Comment: Show the code which writes to csv

Comment: i am using scrapy so in the settings.py file it has 

FEED_FORMAT = "csv"
FEED_URI = "alibaba.csv"

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you trim the scraped string?

Notes here https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip

Something like (Guessing based on your code snippet)

```
 scraped_info = {
            'link':item[0].strip(),

        }
```

Comment: What is the variable that is causing the problem? I was guessing which one to use. Strip will strip whitespace. I can't see your data, so not sure which field to strip.

Comment: can i do this? scraped_info = scraped_info.strip()

Comment: No. You will end up in applying strip() function for a dict() object then.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
response.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@class="column one3"]/a/@href)').extract()
```

Comment: XPath error: Unregistered function in normsize-space(//*[@class="column one3"]/a/@href)

Comment: XPath error: Unregistered function in normsize-space(//*[@class="column one3"]/a/@href)

Comment: @UchihaAJ You have a typo: it's `normalize-space` but your error message is about `normsize-space`